# Firebase on Android : DataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() is returning 0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase realtime database :

[image: Firebase Databse]

This is my code :

```
            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);

            final String s1 = t1.getText().toString();

            mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("name")
                    .equalTo(s1)
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                                    tv2.setText(Long.toString(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
                        }
                     }
```

I am entering these values in EditText fields :

```
            editText10 => Anupam Singh
```

dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() should be 1 but it is coming to be 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of hand written *DB Structure*, Please add screenshot from firebase, which gives correct information

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AnupamSingh check my answer

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @AnupamSingh Have you tried Peter's answer?

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried, nothing gets displayed and the control goes to parent activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database you have the following:

```
users
    name_title_company_location
```

Therefore the attribute `name_title_company_location` is a direct child under node`users`. When you are using `orderByChild`, you are not accessing that node.

What you need to do is add an `id` in the database:

```
users
    id
     name_title_company_location
```

Then your code will work.

---

Or you can change the code to the following, go one level up:

```
mDatabase.orderByChild("name_title_company_location").equalTo(...)
```

Comment: I guess name is in S1. Kindly check the question

Comment: I tried this solution but control goes to parent activity.

Comment: Exception was in different part of code. Your solution works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-the issue is in orderByChild.
-you have pass query and ask for single value event listener.

do as below :

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

```
     Query query =  mDatabase.("name_title_company_location")
                .equalTo(s1 + "_" + s2 + "_" + s3 + "_" + s4);

                query.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                                tv2.setText(Long.toString(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
                    }
                 }
```

-it will return the data